# Flask app still in development mode despite using production config?

Tags: flask

I am confused by the DEBUG and production/development settings running flask.

I have setup my config file as classes

```
app.config.from_object("config.Production")
```

For demonstration my class use has more content.

```
class Production(Config):
    DEBUG = False
    ...
```

I also use a .env file which only includes

```
FLASK_ENV=production
FLASK_APP=run
```

Running the app in this way show this in the terminal

```
* Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
```

I am confused how to handle (and use) the differences between FLASK_ENV and what is set in the config file. Debug mode is always on despite setting my env as in production? It feels like I am missing something fundamental about how env and config is handled?

Comment: Did you mean `DEBUG = False`, not uppercase?

Comment: yes correct, typed it in wrong in my post. Its False in code

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/

Comment: Yes, on the production side I use gevent. But i still dont understand why Debug mode is on when i specify in my config it should not be?